# javascript passing input without entering input fields/forms

Tags: javascript

Yesterday i wrote a question here but the way i did that request was kinda confusing.

Now I'll try it different.

I have a barcode handscanner which just scans the barcode and writes the input into an input field.
It's just the same as a guy who typs 10 digits and presses return in less then 5ms.

example : 2134463342 + return

Now i have a form which was set to autofocus on reload and i can get the input from the scanner.

I want to be able to do scans and passing them into a database without entering the input field.

example: User does something else like browsing the webpage than the user scans something without entering the input field.

I have copied some code from a site:

```
    var chars = []; 
    $(window).keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) {
            chars.push(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
        }
        console.log(e.which + ":" + chars.join("|"));
        if (pressed == false) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (chars.length >= 10) {
                    var barcode = chars.join("");
                    console.log("Barcode Scanned: " + barcode);
                    // assign value to some input (or do whatever you want)
                    $("#barcode").val(barcode);
                }
                chars = [];
                pressed = false;
            },500);
        }
        pressed = true;
    });
});
$("#barcode").keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 13 ) {
        console.log("Prevent form submit.");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The code works fine, my Question is: 
Is it possible to do that operation without entering the input field/form?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@alexMmM 
did you tried CSS to hide the inputbox??? `style= display:none`  or `style= visibility:hidden` property ???
It hides your input box and gives a virtual feel that it has been done without entering into input fields...

Comment: some times css would help to do more virtual tasks like these.consider voteup or accepting

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I solved it with a different solution but your idea helped me out. If i do it hidden it's not going to be autofocused but I did height and width 00.1. So it's not visible to all users.